# Is there any way to create an empty folder using DotNetZip?

Tags: .net, zip, dotnetzip

I'm trying to use DotNetZip to create a zip file in C#.NET.  However, I do need to include empty folders from time to time.  Is this possible?  Are there any tricks to make it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an AddDirectory function:

```
zipFile.AddDirectory("\\Your\Directory\Path\");
```

I believe the empty directory must already exist at the location you are zipping from, so you may need to first create the empty directory on the server.  [Here](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html) are some examples.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  It didn't even need to exist at the location I was zipping from.  It just created the folder in the zip.

Answer (score 2):

McCee's solution didn't quite work for me. This however did:

First we get all the empty directories in the path of files to zip. Then we use AddDirectoryByName to append it to the zip object, i.e.

```
foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(pathOfFilesToZip).Where(x => !Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(x).Any()))
{
    zip.AddDirectoryByName(Path.GetFileName(folder));
}
```